# QGIS Change treeview categories in browser(2) panel

Tags: qgis, qgis-browser

The main categories of the treeview in the browser panel seem to be hard coded. Is it possible to

1.) add, delete or rename categories (e.g. instead of "Project home" name it "Data")

2.) link "Home" to another directory (e.g. a subdirectory of c:\Users\)

I want to get rid of all the entries in the Home category which have nothing to do with GIS, and let it point to a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. I suggest you use the favorites functionality to configure shortcuts to your GIS data folders.

Comment: Thanks for this time saving info. Concerning the rename issue: I altered the qgis_XX.ts file (Project home -> Data) and rebuilt the qm file. Hmm, but it works.